# App will be slow when the number of spans increase

Tags: android, performance, html

The question that increasing the number of spans in android application leads the slowness of reaction has frustrated me! If there are any other method to make application speed up ?

In my application, If I press a virtual keyboard, a new span such as a picture span is added into edittext. At first, it is quick and timely. But when the spans are more than 300, the reaction of my app is slow when I continue type. Especially when I insert span in the front of the text, it will cost more than 1 minute to bring it into text.

The following describes how I add spans into my text:

```
//if a key is pressed, insert a new span in the front of text:
SpanItem item = new SpanItem(xxxx);
editable.insert(0, "r"); //r will be replaced by item.
editable.setSpan(item, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE;
```

Do you have any good methods to improve the speed of the app??
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on Google for Spannable took me to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.Factory.html. Factories are often put in place to handle resource management and reuse. I assuming your SpanItem implements Spannable, if so use the Factory this will solve your problem.